# Lua-error driving me crazy

Tags: lua

I keep getting this error and I cannot find it. Please help.
LUA ERROR: Cannot load buffer.
[string "LuaMacros script"]:191: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 85) near '['

Here is the script:

```
--Start Script

sendToAHK = function (key)

    --print('It was assigned string:    ' .. key)

    local file = io.open("C:\\Users\\TaranWORK\\Documents\\GitHub\\2nd-keyboard-master\\LUAMACROS\\keypressed.txt", "w") -- writing this string to a text file on disk is probably NOT the best method. Feel free to program something better!

    --Make sure to substitute the path that leads to your own "keypressed.txt" file, using the double backslashes.

    --print("we are inside the text file")

    file:write(key)

    file:flush() --"flush" means "save"

    file:close()

    lmc_send_keys('{F24}')  -- This presses F24. Using the F24 key to trigger AutoHotKey is probably NOT the best method. Feel free to program something better!

end



local config = { -- this is line 85

    [45]  = "insert",

    [36]  = "home",

    [33]  = "pageup",

    [46]  = "delete",

    [35]  = "end",

    [34]  = "pagedown",

    [27]  = "escape",

    [112] = "F1",

    [113] = "F2",

    [114] = "F3",

    [115] = "F4",

    [116] = "F5",

    [117] = "F6",

    [118] = "F7",

    [119] = "F8",

    [120] = "F9",

    [121] = "F10",

    [122] = "F11",

    [123] = "F12",

    [8]   = "backspace",

    [220] = "backslash",

    [13]  = "enter",

    [16]  = "rShift",

    [17]  = "rCtrl",

    [38]  = "up",

    [37]  = "left",

    [40]  = "down",

    [39]  = "right",

    [32]  = "space",

    [186] = "semicolon",

    [222] = "singlequote",

    [190] = "period",

    [191] = "slash",

    [188] = "comma",

    [219] = "leftbracket",

    [221] = "rightbracket",

    [189] = "minus",

    [187] = "equals",

    [96]  = "num0",

    [97]  = "num1",

    [98]  = "num2",

    [99]  = "num3",

    [100] = "num4",

    [101] = "num5",

    [102] = "num6",

    [103] = "num7",

    [104] = "num8",

    [105] = "num9",



    [106] = "numMult",

    [107] = "numPlus",

    [108] = "numEnter" --sometimes this is different, check your keyboard

    [109] = "numMinus",

    [110] = "numDelete",

    [111] = "numDiv",

    [144] = "numLock", --probably it is best to avoid this key. I keep numlock ON, or it has unexpected effects



    [192] = "`",  --this is the tilde key just before the number row

    [9]   = "tab",

    [20]  = "capslock",

    [18]  = "alt",





    [string.byte('Q')] = "q",

    [string.byte('W')] = "w",

    [string.byte('E')] = "e",

    [string.byte('R')] = "r",

    [string.byte('T')] = "t",

    [string.byte('Y')] = "y",

    [string.byte('U')] = "u",

    [string.byte('I')] = "i",

    [string.byte('O')] = "o",

    [string.byte('P')] = "p",

    [string.byte('A')] = "a",

    [string.byte('S')] = "s",

    [string.byte('D')] = "d",

    [string.byte('F')] = "f",

    [string.byte('G')] = "g",

    [string.byte('H')] = "h",

    [string.byte('J')] = "j",

    [string.byte('K')] = "k",

    [string.byte('L')] = "l",

    [string.byte('Z')] = "z",

    [string.byte('X')] = "x",

    [string.byte('C')] = "c",

    [string.byte('V')] = "v",

    [string.byte('B')] = "b",

    [string.byte('N')] = "n",

    [string.byte('M')] = "m",



    [string.byte('0')] = "0",

    [string.byte('1')] = "1",

    [string.byte('2')] = "2",

    [string.byte('3')] = "3",

    [string.byte('4')] = "4",

    [string.byte('5')] = "5",

    [string.byte('6')] = "6",

    [string.byte('7')] = "7",

    [string.byte('8')] = "8",

    [string.byte('9')] = "9",



    --[255] = "printscreen" --these keys do not work

}



    -- define callback for whole device

lmc_set_handler('MACROS', function(button, direction)

    --Ignoring upstrokes ensures keystrokes are not registered twice, but activates faster than ignoring downstrokes. It also allows press and hold behaviour

    if (direction == 0) then return end -- ignore key upstrokes.

    if type(config[button]) == "string" then

        print(' ')

        print('Your key ID number is:   ' .. button)

        print('It was assigned string:    ' .. config[button])

        sendToAHK(config[button])

    else

        print(' ')

        print('Not yet assigned: ' .. button)

    end

end)
```

Comment: it's actually pretty simple. { starts a table constructor. it is usually followed by table elements, separated by commas. so where would Lua expect a } to close the table constructor? After the last element provided! and what is the last element in a comma-separated list?

Answer (score 3):

There's a comma missing after the string here:

```
[108] = "numEnter" --sometimes this is different, check your keyboard
```